# Nginx - another root for a specific location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have some static html files under:

```
/var/www/project1
```

Nginx config for this project is:

```
server_name             www.project1.com project1.com;
root                    /var/www/project1;

location / {
    index           index.html;
}
```

My goal is to use nginx so that when a user enters this url:

```
www.project1.com/project2
```

Nginx uses another root, I have tried:

```
 location /project2 {
     root /var/www/project2;
     index index.html;
}
```

But this is not working. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: what is your actual path for project2? Is it ``/var/log/project2``? You should use ``root /var/www`` in your location for project2 or you will be looking for files under ``/var/www/project2/project2``

Comment: @Lution, thx, that fixed the issue. In fact, the path of project2 is `/var/www/project2`. Could you please answer this and I'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your config of project2

```
location /project2 {
    root /var/www/project2;
    index index.html;
}
```

Nginx will be looking for files under the path `/var/www/project2/project2/` for your requests to project2. So if your project2 is under `/var/www/project2`, The correct config should be

```
location /project2 {
    root /var/www;
    index index.html;
}
```

Another alternative is to use `alias` instead of `root`.

in your case is `alias /var/www/project2`, check [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)