# nginx: how to use multiple roots for multiple locations, including / ? (what's wrong with my paths config?)

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup nginx for first test uses, without a domain yet.

My current goal is to show some page at `http://<server IP>` and serve some static content at `http://<server IP>/projectname`. The "some page" is currently just the default `/var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html`.

In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` I've created a `projectname` config and I've put a link to sites-enabled:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/tiddlywiki /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

The first version of config was

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name <server IP>;

    root /some/path/to/project/static-files;
    index index.html;

    location /projectname {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

What I got, is `http://<server IP>` started serving static files, but `http://<server IP>/projectname` showed 404. **How do I fix that?** Because next step, I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37481645/3995261) and tried to set 2 locations:

```
    location /projectname {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.nginx-debian.html;
    }
```

but only got the default page at `http://<server IP>` back again, and 404 at `http://<server IP>/projectname`.

Comment: In the first block, Nginx is trying to serve `/some/path/to/project/static-files/projectname/index.html` but is telling you that the file is not found or cannot be read. In the second case, I do not know, as the value of `root` inherited by the `location /projectname` block is not stated in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was, with `root` directive, path is *concatenated* to the root, so with this config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name <server IP>;

    root /some/path/to/project/static-files;
    index index.html;

    location /projectname {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.nginx-debian.html;
    }
}
```

nginx tried to serve `/projectname` → `/some/path/to/project/static-files/projectname` which is an unexisting folder (existing one is `/some/path/to/project/static-files`). What I needed is the `alias` directive:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name <server IP>;

    index index.html;

    location /projectname {
        alias /some/path/to/project/static-files;
        index index.html;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.nginx-debian.html;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how exactly `try_files` works so I've removed it for now and also added the `index` directive.